# Sonar coverage and unit tests working, but cannot view test sources

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

I'm generating coverage and unit test reports with js testdriver and then using the output with sonar runner.

Although all the sources appear in sonar along with correct test coverage and test results, whenever I click on source for the tests themselves I just get "Could not find source for unit test: Chrome_290154776_Windows.CurrencyTest in any of test directories"

See the following screen shots:

[image: test report shows up]
[image: source does not]

The only obvious thing I notice is that the browser/os name has been added to the test class name, but that hasn't been an issue before, is this fine usually?

Additionally if I try and view coverage by clicking on "Coverage" on the dashboard and then browsing to the classes which are unit tested, they don't appear. I can however browse to the class manually (clicking files from the dashboard for example) and even bring up the code coverage from there!

See these to illustrate:

[image: covered classes missing]
[image: but you can browse to them and see coverage too]

Could this be a result of the previous problem or is it unrelated?

As far as I can see sonar.tests in sonar-project.properties is pointing to the correct directory. My folders are laid out like this:

```
myProject > src > main
myProject > src > test
myProject > target
```

sonar-project.properties looks like this

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=Core-1.0-SNAPSHOT
sonar.projectName=Core
sonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT

# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src/main

# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=src/test

# Advanced parameters
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=target/jstd
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=target/jstd/jsTestDriver.conf-coverage.dat
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=js

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Additional parameters
# sonar.my.property=value
```

I'm reaching the end of my tether with this, it just isn't making any sense to me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers